# Stock code/framework for Guess the word game - keyboard UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview

I'm learning iOS development and trying to make a standard common "Guess the word" game, which displays a couple of photos and you need to fill the word which describes this photos.

I took a look in at the app store and see a lot of games which use a same UI keyboard view. For example:

[image]

My question is if there is any open source framework for this kind of keyboard or I should build a new one by dynamically add a few Labels\Images according to the letters and handle the touch events and fill the letters?

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't be particularly difficult to create a view such as this. It's a trivial view hierarchy with 13 buttons in fixed positions.

Use it as a learning exercise and implement it yourself, you could do it mostly in Interface Builder as a nib, a custom `UIView` subclass with a nice delegate interface such as this:

```
@protocol GameKeyboardDelegate

// Called when a letter button is tapped
- (void)gameKeyboard:(GameKeyboard *)keyboard tappedKeyWithName:(NSString *)keyName;

// Called when the bomb button is tapped
- (void)gameKeyboardTappedBomb:(GameKeyboard *)keyboard;

// Provided to let your game logic determine whether or not the bomb button should be enabled.
- (BOOL)gameKeyboardShouldEnableBombButton:(GameKeyboard *)keyboard;

@end
```